# Can I improve this algorithm using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm creating a collection of one to one mappings from Foo to Baa.

Baa contains a collection of unique instances of Foo.

Here's some code that does the job:

```
Dictionary<Foo, Baa> mappings = new Dictionary<Foo, Baa>();

foreach (Baa baa in CollectionOfBaa)
{
    foreach (Foo foo in baa.CollectionOfFoo)
    {
        mappings.Add(foo, baa);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this using LINQ?

I'm not adverse to replacing the dictionary with a list of KeyValuePair.

Thanks.

Comment: Linq will always be slower than foreach loops (due to added overhead).  If your foreach loop works, stick with it.

Comment: @Herbie: Performance is not as important as readability in most cases. I've not found a significantly more readable LINQ version, though. =)

Comment: Readability is subjective, right? For me the foreach version is the most readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summerising all the comments and answers we get:

**Speed:** Using LINQ is actually slower.

**Readability:** This is a subjective point, but I agree with all the comments stating that the original foreach loops are the most readable.

I'm going to stick with the original code.

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 5):

You could use

```
var mappings = (from baa in CollectionOfBaa
                from foo in  baa.CollectionOfFoo
                select new { foo, baa }).ToDictionary(e => e.foo, e=> e.baa);
```

Comment: Wow, awesome ineffectiveness. Doing 3 foreach loops, creating n temporary objects and invoking n*2-times an anonymous function.
And it does not even add readability (IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

Improve how? Performance? **No**. Readability? **Not for me**.

Well, maybe this for readability (I still prefer the foreach version though)?

```
CollectionOfBaa.ForEach(baa =>
    baa.ForEach(foo =>
        mappings.Add(foo, baa)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var keyValuePairs = from baa in CollectionOfBaa
                    from foo in baa.CollectionOfFoo
                    select new KeyValuePair(baa,foo);

foreach item in keyValuePairs
{
mappings.Add(item.key,item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since KeyValuePairs are acceptable, consider an IEnumerable of them:

```
var mappings = from parent in CollectionOfBaa
               from child in parent.CollectionOfFoo
               select new KeyValuePair<Foo,Baa>(child, parent);
```